# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: while using loader component with loader intercepter service

Tags: angular, angular7

Suddenly i started getting the below console error without changing the code.

```
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.
```

In this html line

```
<div id="cover" *ngIf="show && (router.url === '/inventory/overview' || router.url === '/inventory/details')" class="loader-cover">
```

LoaderInterceptorService - from this service show variable is changed

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your @Component object : changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

like this :

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss']
})
```

And import ChangeDetectionStrategy from '@angular/core'

Comment: Can you explain what this does?